# Passing user input values through Querystring without code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink, query-string

I'm trying to generate a report through my site.

Default.aspx has a dropdownlist and 2 textboxes. The report (which is generated on a different page) must use all of the values from these 3 controls in the sql query used to collect the data from SQL Server.

**Concept**
The user can leave all 3 fields with their default values, or change any of them. After deciding what values the user wants to see a report on, they can click a `HyperLink control` to open to the report page in a new tab.

The value from the DropDownList is passed through to Report.aspx via a Session variable set on `SelectedIndexChanged`. Report.aspx reads this and should read the Text values for the 2 textboxes as well.

**Problem**
I can't figure out how to send the values of the TextBoxes through to Report.aspx. I thought of doing the following:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="lnkReport"
  NavigateUrl="Report.aspx?fromdate=<%# Eval('txtFromDate.Text') %>&todate=<%# Eval('txtToDate.Text') %>"
  target="_blank" Text="Generate Report"></asp:HyperLink>
```

I'm not sure this would work though, as Eval typically requires a parent control to be data bound - as far as I'm aware anyway.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I asked this question, I remembered that the Dropdownlist and textboxes are used to bind a GridView on Default.aspx and I used this to my advantage here.

I know that one way or another, the GridView absolutely **has** to be bound before I click to generate the report, so I set session variables there to store the information that the report requires.

```
Dim db As New Database

Dim sql As String = "select * from users where userid = @id and dateregistered between @fromdate and @todate"

Dim args As New List(Of SqlParameter)
args.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", ddlUsers.SelectedItem.Value))
args.Add(New SqlParameter("@fromdate", txtFromDate.Text))
args.Add(New SqlParameter("@todate", txtToDate.Text))

gvItems.DataSource = db.GetDataReader(sql, args.ToArray())
dvItems.DataBind()

Session("userid") = ddlUsers.SelectedItem.Value
Session("fromdate") = txtFromDate.Text
Session("todate") = txtToDate.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery or Javascript You could just call a a client side function to get the values from the form elements, construct the url and open a new window?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a HyperLink, you could use a link button to do some cross page posting.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkReport"
  NavigateUrl="~/Report.aspx"
  target="_blank" Text="Generate Report"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then on **Report.aspx.cs**:

Get the values from the [Page.PreviousPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) as follows:

```
DropDownList userid = (DropDownList)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("ddlUsers");
TextBox fromdate = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("fromdate");
TextBox todate = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("todate");
```

Use these as you require in your reports page.